# How to get the global effect of a categorical variable with mice

Tags: categorical-data, mice

I try to perform 2 models after multiple imputation  with MICE (package mice in R) : a logistic regression and a Cox regression models with random effect. I'd like to get the global pooled effect of the categorical covariates (with more than 2 classes).

R gives the pooled coefficients, p values and 95%CI for each class of the categorical covariates. How can I get the overall coefficients, p values and 95%IC of the categorical covariates? I tried to use drop1 that gives the p values of each imputed data sets but I can't pool the results.

Thank you for your help

Arnaud